# Hide uploaded files from search results?

Tags: php, wordpress, robots.txt

A client running WordPress has requested the development of the following feature on their website.

They would like to include/exclude specific files (typically PDF) uploaded via the WordPress media uploader from search results.

I'm guessing this could be done somehow using a robots.txt file, but I have no idea where to start.

Any advice/ideas?

Comment: It's an existing client. But yeah, excellent theory. Stick to what you know, don't take on any jobs that could prove challenging. That's a sure-fire way to self development and improving your skillset.

Comment: doing web-development jobs and not knowing what is robots.txt, how it works and not doing any research with google before you ask a question is a sign, that you're doing your job wrong. Not even close to challenging. You want to prove you're not lazy "gimme the codez" guy - start research and show us that you've even tried to solve **your** problem. What's your current efforts apart of asking here?

Comment: Who said I don't understand robots.txt files? The problem I face is setting up an option within the WordPress media uploader to include/exclude the uploaded file from search results. I've been Googling (unsuccessfully) for the past 30 minutes, which is why I'm here.

Comment: "Who said I don't understand robots.txt files?" "I'm **guessing** this could be done **somehow** using a robots.txt file, but I **have no idea** where to start." Anyway, I've said what I think. Let's see if anyone could help

Comment: I'm not looking for code to copy/paste. I'm simply looking for some general direction and/or ideas on how to approach the issue.

Comment: are all the files you want to exclude going in to one directory? are you excluding all or is exclusion (or not) set on upload? I'm a little unsure of some of the finer points here.

Comment: At the moment, all files are included in search results. Perhaps it's possible to specify the destination folder of uploaded files? If so, I could then manually edit the robots.txt file to accommodate.

Comment: well using a robots.txt to exclude one directory is easy, if you can upload the files there, and i must assume you can set the destination - but i have never used word-press.

Comment: Ok. Cheers. I'll see if it's possible to choose the destination folder inside WordPress and I'll go from there. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is from Google Webmaster Developers site https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/faq

How long will it take for changes in my robots.txt file to affect my search results?

First, the cache of the robots.txt file must be refreshed (we generally cache the contents for up to one day). Even after finding the change, crawling and indexing is a complicated process that can sometimes take quite some time for individual URLs, so it's impossible to give an exact timeline. Also, keep in mind that even if your robots.txt file is disallowing access to a URL, that URL may remain visible in search results despite that fact that we can't crawl it. If you wish to expedite removal of the pages you've blocked from Google, please submit a removal request via Google Webmaster Tools.

And here are specifications for robots.txt from Google https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt

If your file's syntax is correct the best answer is just wait till Google updates your new robots file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain how to do this within the confines of WordPress, but if you're looking to exclude particular file types, I would suggest using the [X-Robots-Tag HTTP Header](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag). It's particularly great for PDFs and non-HTML based file types where you would normally want to use a  robots tag.

You can add the header for all specific FileType requests and then set a value of NOINDEX. This will prevent the PDFs from being included in the search results.

You can use the robots.txt file if the URLs end with the filetype or something that is unique to the file type. Example: `Disallow: /*.pdf$` ... but I know that's not always the case with URLs.

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag